# Noisy Hub - Does the EVP cover it?

Tags: axle

Not a mechanic, but I've changed hubs before, so I know the sound when one is starting to go out.  Ours is, but the real question is "Is it covered?"  We have a vehicle protection policy and part of it reads:

*

> Final drive and axle housings and all internally.  -  lubricated
>   parts, flex discs, axle shafts and bearings, universal and constant
>   velocity joints, drive shaft, center bearings, drive shaft yokes.

*

The key word being "bearings".  Does that mean the hub bearings are going to be covered or are they more considered normal wear & tear like tires?

https://www.usaa.com/inet/pages/extended_vehicle_protection_program_details?lookAndFeel=iframe_gadget&ucsp=lookAndFeel

Comment: That is something you need to ask your policy issuer. Any answer here will be pure speculation on our part.

Answer (score 1):

I say, from the wording, that they are.

Comment: I agree with your assessment.